# Trying to get mean of ratings from a certain director from my database, but I get the same results for a movie many times

Tags: sql

So I have a school project where I have my database set up like this:

[image: DATABASE]

I'm trying to get the mean of a certain directors movie ratings with this sql command:

```sql
SELECT rating 
FROM ratings 
JOIN movies ON ratings.movie_name=movies.name 
JOIN users ON users.id = ratings.user_id 
WHERE movies.director= :name AND ratings.user_id = users.id
```

Instead of giving the correct output, it counts certain ratings many times.
For example if a movie has 3 ratings it counts each rating 3 times. So if let's say Pulp Fiction has ratings (8, 9, 10) and i use the fetchall command, I get (8,8,8,9,9,9,10,10,10) and not just (8, 9 ,10).

Any tips on what I'm doing wrong in the SELECT command?

Comment: Do you simply want `SELECT DISTINCT`?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT Doesn't give all ratings if users have given the same rating

Comment: A [mcve] would make things clearer here. Note that sample table data and expected result should be given as (properly) formatted text (no links, no images.)